# SharePoint - simplest solution and feature config to register a server control?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, wss-3.0

I would like to know what the XML is for the simplest feature and that will register a Server Control in the GAC, and add it the safe controls section of the web.config for the SharePoint site.

My assembly:

MyServerControl.dll (MyServerControl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3249363c0f6f8c59)

I can manually add it to the GAC with gacutil /i, but I want to have the feature do this for me and also add an element to SafeControls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a feature cannot add files to the GAC, that's a job for a solution. The solution can deploy your feature to the 12 hives, the assembly to the GAC and can add a safe controls entry to the web.config.

[MSDN on Solutions and Web Part Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413687.aspx)

As building a MOSS solution by hand can be a lot of pain, there are some cool tools out there which can support you on that.

[VSeWSS 1.3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=B2C0B628-5CAB-48C1-8CAE-C34C1CCBDC0A&displaylang=en)
[WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to build a solution package to deploy your user control's assembly into the GAC.  A feature doesn't deploy assemblies.  In fact a feature isn't even needed to deploy a user control.  Check out my post which contains instructions and sample code on how to get started.

[Deploying a User Control in SharePoint](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/11/18/introduction-to-sharepoint-development-deploy-a-user-control-in-sharepoint.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

WSPBuilder is the way to go, it will automatically add the dll's to the GAC, and if necessary, register it as a SafeControl in the web application you deploy the solution to.